# Help identifying an insect by its remains

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Yesterday i hiked in Bolsena lake, Italy. I felt this insect moving into my ear. So i smashed my ear and this is the result. Please tell me that there are no risks related to Lyme desease or similar.
Sorry for the bad quality of the photo.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a beetle.
The shape of legs and the two big eyes are an insect thing.
Lyme desease is transmitted by ticks, so i would not worry.

Comment: Thank you. One more question: so beetles could own wings?

Comment: @FedericoJuvara many (though not all) beetles have wings. They're usually protected and hidden under the elytra when not in use though. Check out https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beetle#Wings for a picture and more information.

Comment: I'll check it out, thank you very much!